# What are high-frequency/low-frequency signals in an image?

Tags: image, image-processing, signal-processing, highpass-filter

I often encountered the term high-frequency/low-frequency signals in an image. And relevantly, high-pass filters for sharpening. I have a hard time relating the word frequency with 2d images. An image is simply a 2-d array of 3 values (r,g,b). What does frequency mean in this context? And how does a high-pass filter become sharpening the image?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to [fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) (AFAIK, `t` in the formula is `x,y` of pixel coordinate).
Roughly speaking :-

```
high-frequency = high-signal when convoluted with high-frequency function      
              && relatively low-signal when convoluted with low-frequency function

low-frequency = vice-versa
```

I am not so strong in this area.
To avoid stealing their contents, here are all good links.
They should contain information more than you need :-

- https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40401/what-does-frequency-mean-in-an-image (image & code)
- https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node223.html (very short)
- https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/what-does-frequency-domain-denote-in-case-of-images (simple image and show fourier transform)